# How to add properties via Spring TestExecutionListener

Tags: spring-test

I created a `TestExecutionListener` to run a docker container for integration testing. I would like to be able to inject properties (eg container port) that can be used by `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans.

I thought I might be able to call `TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(...)` but when I try to get an application context object the context ends up fully loading before I can even attempt to inject any properties.

Is there any way to do this from a `TestExecutionListener`?

My workaround is to set the properties via `System.setProperty(...)` but that obviously does not permit any concurrency.

I'm running Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE.